# How to use a Smart TV as a wireless display?

Tags: windows-8.1, smart-tv

I have a Samsung smart TV (S6) with built-in WiFi adapter. Is it possible to use it as a wireless monitor?

Currently, I can use "play to" option on Windows Explorer and some other third party software to play music, video and images on the TV wirelessly.
I want to use the TV as a regular monitor.

Comment: For experience, I wouldn't recommend it. While @JulianKnight pointed out correctly how to use the TV as secondary monitor, I can tell that performance is hear horrible, just because it is laggy. You will move your mouse and have to wait up to a half second to be displayed the move.

Miracast is only good for PowerPoint presentations IMO. No gaming, no CAD, no cinema, nothing that requires real-time response

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible options:

- Some Samsung TV's support WIDI (Intel Wireless Display) that may work.
- Miracast is another wireless display standard and some Samsung TV's also support this. [It is supported in Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/project-wireless-screen-miracast)
- You could also set up your PC as a DLNA server which the TV would be able to pick up though that is only for media. There are plenty of PC options for this but the built-in media player does it natively.

Comment: I have no problem with third option. My TV support Miracast but, there is no option named 'Add a wireless display' in my Windows.

Comment: @PHPst - Did you look in the right place?  Because I promise you its there.

Comment: Do you have a WiDi-enabled graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your TV. For example, my Samsung support Screen Mirroring which allows this sort of remote display from a computer or mobile device with some additional software. Or, have a look at this link for ways to do it, with some additional hardware, with any TV.

http://compnetworking.about.com/od/consumerelectronicsn...